# Столкнулся с новой проблемой, кто подскажет в чем ошибка?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте. написал код выбора по типу и с промежутком. но столкнулся с такой проблемой.
1) при выборе например Типа - Доход и даты с 01.05.2020 по 10.05.2020, показываются "Доход"-ы только за 05-е и 10-е числа, а за 1-е нет. почему так?

2) при добавлении новой записи (Доход/Расход) она отображается в форме поиска но при фильтрации по типу и датам не находится, хотя попадает в нужный промежуток по дате, почему так?

```
OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Path.Combine(new FileInfo(Application.ExecutablePath).DirectoryName, "База данных.mdb"));
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            myConnection.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM Accounting WHERE (Дата BETWEEN @date1 and @date2) and Тип = @data";
            OleDbDataAdapter oleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, myConnection);
            oleDbDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", dateTimePicker1.Value);
            oleDbDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", dateTimePicker2.Value);
            oleDbDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", cbSearch.Text);
            oleDbDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            myConnection.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Вероятно, в вашем диалекте SQL оператор between не включает первую или обе границы. Вам нужно это уточнить и или вычислить предыдущий день для параметра @date1, или модифицировать аргумент BETWEEN прямо в SQL.

Comment: а можно простым языком или если не затруднит точно указать что куда и как. я новичок, поэтому многое еще не понимаю.

Comment: Попробуйте в запросе вместо BETWEEN написать `(Дата >= @date1 and Дата <= @date2)`

Comment: Вангую, что dateTimePicker1.Value выдаёт дату с ненулевым временем (хотя не знаю каким именно), а в базе дата без времени, соответственно, ваша дата-время получается больше, чем та, которая в базе, вот и не попадает в диапазон.

Comment: @vp_arth  попробовал как вы посоветовали но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Значит проблема не в sql. Проверьте версию Эльфа, что у вас лежит в dateTimePicker1.Value?

Comment: Инициализация полей датой `dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.Date;` должна решить проблему. По умолчанию, поля инициализируются текущими датой и **временем**

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос 1) решил.  вот решение `oleDbDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);`

теперь кто поможет решить вопрос номер 2, пожалуйста?